# Create paper_trail New Version without updating existing Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, paper-trail-gem

I've integrated paper_trail with a Project Model.

**Normal Flow:-**

Whenever project Record in model gets updated, a new version with changes gets created in Versions table.

**Requirement:-**

Whenever any project gets updated, rather than updating project record itself in projects model, i want to create a new Version Record. is there any way to do it ?

I'm using Rails 5.1.6.2, paper_trail (10.3.0)

Comment: Just to clarify: You want a project to not change in the database when it is updated and to still show the old attributes after an update? Only a new version should be created? How do you know that a new version exists when the original record in the database never changes?

Comment: @spickermann once the form is submitted, it will call update action in controller. i want to store all these changes in version rather changing the real Object. then later, based on version changes, Admin will approve/reject the changes and modify the original Project Record.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try using `PaperTrail::Events::Update`, though it's not public API (it may change at any time without warning)

```
project.name = 'new name'
update = PaperTrail::Events::Update.new(project, ....)
PaperTrail::Version.create!(update.data)
```

Again, this is not public API, so you will void your warranty :)

> Whenever any project gets updated, ..

I'd put this in my `ProjectController#update` action only. You could use a model callback like `before_save` if you really have to, and `throw :abort` to [halt](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#halting-execution) the callback chain, but you'll have to work around the implicit transaction.

- https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/blob/master/lib/paper_trail/events/update.rb

Answer (score 0):

We also have this flow in our app where a user can edit a record, but the edits have to be approved or rejected before going live. So we use PaperTrail as intended, but then immediately rollback the changes and created a workflow for the approval/rejection that reinstates them or not.